# What's causing horizontal scroll bar in chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Is there way to figure out what web page element of https://cummings.ee/ is causing horizontal scroll bar in the page footer in Google Chrome.  This scroll bar doesn't occur in the Firefox.

[image]

Comment: Using Chrome on Mac does not have a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: @Karl It seems that "In OS X Lion (on Mac), scrollbars are hidden by default and only shown when being used (even though "overflow:scroll" is set)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the "overflow: scroll" on the body element. Use "overflow-y:auto"

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using "overflow: auto" as it seems to solve the issue